# Referencing 3rd party components in Delphi 2005

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2005

I'm quite new to Delphi and I'm helping a team setting up a build server which are using Rad Studio 2005.

They have just bought DevExpress VCL and wants to use these. I would rather not have the component installed on the build server, but instead having them as a part of the source code and making sure that the project is using that version.

How is that done in Delphi?

Comment: JENKINS/Hudson works well with Delphi and MSBuild in Delphi 2007 and up.  Why is this q tagged 2005 AND XE2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We compiled all of our 3rd-party stuff into a BPL, then put that .bpl and corresponding .dcp and .dpr/.bdsproje into source control, so it gets delivered to the build server. Works well. In retrospect, it should have been a series of BPLs, divided by vendor, so that we could upgrade individual components/libraries without having to run regression tests on everything else.

Comment: What do you use as build server?

Comment: It's a homebrew thing put together by two different teams of college interns... SQL*Server as a job queue, and a VB.Net app that scans the queue and kicks off jobs which pull the applicable source from SVN, update version resources in the .bdsproj files, then calls the command-line compiler.  Runs on a VM somewhere in the corporate ether.

Comment: Does this mean that you build with run time packages or do you put the components' sources into source control as well and build from source instead?